# How do I programmatically add a property sheet to all build configurations for all projects in a solution?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio

I have a (probably auto-generated with CMake or something similar) solution with 23 projects. Each Projects has 12 different build configurations (Debug, Release, x64, Win32, DLL, static, ...). I have a couple of property sheets that I'd like to "apply" to each build configuration for each project.

I *could* interactively go through each project and build config, but surely there's some way to do the job programmatically.

Is there some way to accomplish this?

I would expect that it's something that could be done with .NET, and it seems most plausible to use the Nu-Get package manager console to accomplish my goal with PowerShell. I did find a starting point, [Get-Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-get-project), though I'm not sure how to get to the build configurations and property sheets.